# How to create a callback function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, callback

I'm having trouble creating a callback function with following scenario:
A kafka consumer listens to new messages to be able to record in the database:

```
suspend fun consumerClient(service: ClientService) {
    val messages = consumerCommands(
        "create-client", "localhost:9092", "consumer-client", false,
        OffsetBehaviour.Earliest, 10
    )
}

suspend fun consumerCommands(
    topic: String,
    bootstrapServers: String,
    group: String,
    autoCommit: Boolean,
    offsetBehaviour: OffsetBehaviour,
    pollMax: Int
) {
    val consumer = consumer(bootstrapServers, group, autoCommit, offsetBehaviour, pollMax)
    consumer.subscribe(mutableListOf(topic))
    while (true) {
        val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
        if (records.count() > 0) {
            records.forEach {
                val entity = treeToValue(it.value().get("message"), Client::class.java) as Client
                ClientService().insert(entity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly. But I'm trying to create something more generic as follows:

```
interface KafkaConsumer<T> {
    fun execute(callback: (T) -> Unit)
}

suspend fun <T> consumerCommand(
    topic: String,
    bootstrapServers: String,
    group: String,
    autoCommit: Boolean,
    offsetBehaviour: OffsetBehaviour,
    pollMax: Int,
    callback: KafkaConsumer<T>
): ConsumerRecords<String, JsonNode>? {
    val consumer = consumer(bootstrapServers, group, autoCommit, offsetBehaviour, pollMax)
    consumer.subscribe(mutableListOf(topic))
    while (true) {
        val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
        if (records.count() > 0) {
            records.forEach {
                val entity = (treeToValue(it.value().get("message"), Any::class.java) as T)
                coroutineScope {
                    callback.execute { entity }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


suspend fun consumerClient(service: ClientService) {
    val messages = consumerCommand<Client>(
        "create-client", "localhost:9092", "consumer-client", false,
        OffsetBehaviour.Earliest, 10, {client: Client -> ClientService().insert(client)}
    )
}
```

But it is not working. Could anyone help?

Comment: Please add information about what is not working. What is the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
suspend fun <T> consumerCommand(
    topic: String,
    bootstrapServers: String,
    group: String,
    autoCommit: Boolean,
    offsetBehaviour: OffsetBehaviour,
    pollMax: Int,
    callback: (entity: T) -> Unit>
): ConsumerRecords<String, JsonNode>? {
    val consumer = consumer(bootstrapServers, group, autoCommit, offsetBehaviour, pollMax)
    consumer.subscribe(mutableListOf(topic))
    while (true) {
        val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
        if (records.count() > 0) {
            records.forEach {
                val entity = (treeToValue(it.value().get("message"), Any::class.java) as T)
                callback(entity)
            }
        }
    }
}

suspend fun consumerClient(service: ClientService) {
    val messages = consumerCommand<Client>(
        "create-client", "localhost:9092", "consumer-client", false,
        OffsetBehaviour.Earliest, 10, {client: Client -> ClientService().insert(client)}
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a lambda `{ client: Client -> ... }` where a `KafkaConsumer` is expected. Instead you need to use a function type. An equivalent of your `KafkaConsumer` would be `((T) -> Unit) -> Unit`, but I suspect it's an error and you actually want

```
suspend fun <T> consumerCommand(
    topic: String,
    bootstrapServers: String,
    group: String,
    autoCommit: Boolean,
    offsetBehaviour: OffsetBehaviour,
    pollMax: Int,
    callback: (T) -> Unit
): ConsumerRecords<String, JsonNode>? {
    ...
                coroutineScope {
                    callback(entity)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or even `suspend (T) -> Unit`.

A side note: you don't use `service` argument in your `consumerClient` function, but instead create a new `ClientService`; is that intentional?